# How would I match multiple elements of a data set by different elements? (e.g. year and company)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-cleaning

I am working with a data set consisting of CSV files and I've been tasked with summing all of a specific data point so that they can be treated as one instead of many. As an example, each record consists of (year, name, ID, value), where ID's, names, and years may repeat. My end goal is a program that effectively looks at each year, then each name in the year, and finally for any identical ID's sums the values. I'm working with the CSV reader built into Python but could use Pandas as well since all the CSV's will be converted to .dta files using it at the end of the project. I know a for loop *would* work for this where I just check each line for duplicate year, name, and ID, however I'm working with one million plus records so optimization would help greatly.

Comment: you can use groupby for this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd

# import csv file
#df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# Toy dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022],
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Charlie', 'Charlie'],
    'ID': ['A001', 'B002', 'A001', 'B002', 'A001', 'C003', 'C003'],
    'value': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
})

# Group by 'year' and 'name' columns and calculate the sum of 'value'
df['total'] = df.groupby(['year', 'name', 'ID'])['value'].transform('sum')

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need speed, [polars](https://www.pola.rs/) has a core written in Rust and is doing very well at the benchmark games. I personally find its API very intuitive. Here's a polars solution to this problem, but as always, benchmark different solutions against your data.

**data.csv**

```
year,name,id,value
2006,bob,1,3
2006,bob,1,4
2007,sally,1,4
```

**main.py**

```py
import polars as pl

q = (
    pl.scan_csv("data.csv")
    .groupby("year", "name", "id")
    .agg((pl.col("value").sum().alias("value_sum"),))
)

q.collect().write_csv("output.csv")
```

**output.csv**

```
year,name,id,value_sum
2007,sally,1,4
2006,bob,1,7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this task in O(n) time complexity. The solution is made trivial with the use of a dictionary. Iterate through each line in your csv and extract the fields. From there, associate the value using your repeated fields as the key. A simple example:

```
mappings = {}
for line in csv:
    tokens = line.split(",")
    id = tokens[0]
    year = tokens[1]
    value = eval(tokens[2])
    if id in mappings:
         mappings[f"{id}-{year}"] += value
    else:
         mappings[f"{id}-{year}"] = value
print(mappings)
```

You will have to modify for your specific use case but adding keys to a dictionary is O(1) time complexity so this is likely the easiest "fast" solution. If after implementing this strategy, you find you need more speed, I'd recommend looking into C++ and threads.